# Should I combine multiple tiles of terrain as one mesh in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, performance, tiles, terrain, mesh

I have a tiled terrain, generated by multiple noise algorithms. Currently, each tile is it's own `GameObject`, that has a handler for an `OnMouseOver` event. The area that is loaded at a time consists of 9 chunks that each contain 4096 tiles. This totals to 36864 tiles that are loaded at a time. On top of this, there are actual objects on top of these tiles.

Is there any considerable performance difference if I were to combine some of these tiles into a single `GameObject` and mesh?

Comment: The best way to know is to profile a test case on your target hardware and find out! We won't be able to tell you what level of performance is acceptable for your game, or how many milliseconds each alternative will take on your device.

Comment: I'm asking about the performance difference between two approaches, the question has nothing to do with acceptable performance for the game itself. I'm trying to get a theoretical answer that would let me decide which approach to take, without implementing both of them to find out why one of them is the better option, or why both of them are equal.

Comment: You know rendering fewer meshes and iterating over fewer mouseover scripts is generally faster — that's no surprise to anyone. The question that will impact your work is: "is it a *big enough* difference in speed to be worth changing my implementation?" And that's a question you're in a much better position to answer than we are. All we can say is "yes, fewer objects is generally faster to some degree, depending on the many specifics of your geometry, rendering, logic, physics, etc..."

Comment: Each Tile has a box collider, and the handler for OnMouseOver event, this is now 36864 tiles that contain those. A bigger mesh creates extra overhead when I have to combine different textures into one. It takes away from the GameObject count and collider count. Knowing these parameters to the question is the gained performance from the decrease of GameObjects bigger then the added overhead? Now the OnMouseOver event also has to calculate the actual Tile from within the mesh that now contains multiple tiles, this adds extra calculations to the event handler. How should I refactor my question?

Comment: Try to think about it in terms of what problem you want to solve — StackExchange is good at solving problems. Is the problem "my game is running slow on my target platform"? Then profile to find which part is slowest (physics, rendering, game logic on the tiles, etc.) and ask about how to improve performance there. On the other hand, if you're not experiencing performance problems, and this setup makes sense to you, then is there any reason to change it?